# Find the remaining KM from given range and Range Value: Min= 0, Max= 999999

Tags: ios, swift

I want calculate  next service due from given odometer range. Range Value: Min= 0, Max= 999999

After every 10000 KM I want show service due.
E.g.
if Odometer value 13400 km then next service due after 6600km (20000-13400 = 6600km)

if Odometer value 184560 km then next service due after 5440km (190000-184560 = 5440km)

I have tried to find this values from given Odometer Range Value: Min= 0, Max= 999999

```
  func firstSolution(odometerValue : Int) -> Int{
        switch odometerValue {
        case 1...10000:
            // print("\(10000-odometerValue)")
            return 10000 - odometerValue

    case 11000...20000 :
        // print("\(20000-odometerValue)")
         return 20000 - odometerValue


    case 21000...30000 :
        //  print("\(30000-odometerValue)")
         return 30000 - odometerValue
}
```

I have tried  for smaller range but i want calculate  for Range Value: Min= 0, Max= 999999

Please help me to calculate using Swift

In advance thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use remainder operator.

`//let  nextServiceIn = 10_000 - odometerValue % 10_000`

Here is example code

```
let testArray = [4557, 15335, 153700, 888888]
testArray.forEach {
    let serviceIn = 10_000 - $0 % 10_000
    print("\($0) -> service in: \(serviceIn) ")
    }
```

Output will be:

```
4557 -> service in: 5443 
15335 -> service in: 4665 
153700 -> service in: 6300 
888888 -> service in: 1112
```